# when i compile on eclipse (c project) and having some arrays in it it doesn't compile it in correct order

Tags: c, eclipse

Here is an example of my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){

int i,number[5];

for (i=0;i<5;i++){
    printf ("Type value\n");
    scanf(" %d",&number[i]);
}
printf("The last number of array is: %d\n",number[4]);
    return 0;
}
```

if I try build project and run , it even says nothing to build or the   terminal looks like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
enter value 
enter value 
enter value 
enter value 
enter value 
The last number of array is: 5
```

Comment: Looks what I would expect... Except of "Type value" instead of "enter value"...

Comment: what order you expected to be printed? The terminal output and your code don't match.

Comment: Eclipse is not a compiler.  What is you compiler and execution environment?  Are you running the executable from the OS command shell or from within Eclipse?  What happens if you do run it in the OS command shell?  Works correctly in my test at https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler#.

Comment: The code you have posted is clearly not the code that generated the output shown - the prompt text differs.

Comment: When you run code from Eclipse, the standard output and standard error are fully buffered, unlike the normal environment where they are more typically line buffered and unbuffered.  To see things a more nearly correct sequence, you will need to make extensive use of `fflush(stdout)` (or perhaps `fflush(0)`) before you try reading.

Comment: Thanks I have put the fflush(stdout) and it worked fine with it.By the way I have a gcc compiler installed and ran the program within eclipse.